# How to Remove Elements from array in php after some given character?

Tags: php

I want to Remove all the Elements from my array which is after `,` but I am unable to do this.

I have an array like this => **["18-08-2022, 05:08:23pm","18-08-2022, 05:09:05pm"]**

and I want to print array something like this => **["18-08-2022","18-08-2022"]**

I want to remove Elements after the `,`

This is what I tried

```
       <?php
         
   
         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                $Etime[] = $row["Etime"];


                $Etime1[]=$row["Etime"];
                $E2[]=substr($Etime1[],',',true);
              

         }
       
   
       

     
         $Etime = json_encode($Etime);
         $Etime1=json_encode($Etime1);
       
         echo $Etime1

        ?>
```

Comment: Are there always only 2 elements? Ex. `['...', '...']`?

Comment: And what is the expected output? A simple array with date strings?

Comment: @waterloomatt yes bro I have mentioned my expected output

Comment: Well, no. You said, "I want to print array something like this => ["18-08-2022","18-08-2022"]". What exactly do you mean by "print"?

Comment: @waterloomatt I have an array like this  ["18-08-2022, 05:08:23pm","18-08-2022, 05:09:05pm"] and I want to remove elemets after ```,``` so I want output like  ["18-08-2022","18-08-2022"]

Comment: Rajesh's answer does just that. `$dateMappedToYourFormat` will contain an array, but the final line formats it as a simple string separated by commas. So, how you want the output formatted? Do you want a simple _string_ that you can echo/print, or an _array_? They are different.

Comment: @waterloomatt I want an array. like ["18-08-2022","18-08-2022"]

Comment: OK, so just remove the final line from Rajesh's answer. `$dateMappedToYourFormat` is an array that only contains the date strings. See https://onlinephp.io/c/e7d7b

Comment: @waterloomatt which line can you please post your answer?

Comment: Let's take this conversation offline. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247375/how-to-remove-elements-from-array-in-php-after-some-given-character

Comment: @waterloomatt I can't cuz I need min 20rep to chat there. If you could share your social ? such as Ig or telegram?

Comment: Sorry mate, can't do. Perhaps edit your question with a clear expected output. For what it's worth, Rajesh's answer is the one you want. You just need to remove the final line of it and use `$dateMappedToYourFormat`. https://onlinephp.io/c/888fc

Answer (score 1):

this is easy-
steps to do so-
1.Parse your array as string.
2.store that in a variable.
3. then use a if loop and use php explode funtion. explode function will seperate that string elements by the seperator in this case the "," you want to remove.

```
 explode(string $separator, string $string)

where,
separator-The boundary string.
string-The input string.
limit

example=
$text = "hello,there";

//using explode-
var_dump( explode( ',', $input2 ) );

output=

array(2)
(
    [0] => string(5) "hello"
    [1] => string(5) "there"
)


more about explode() here- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php
```

Comment: I didn't get it what you are trying to explain how can I achieve my desire output?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple php that generates the output you want. Since you only need date bits I have provided you with only the date bits. You can get general idea from here

```
$arr =  ["18-08-2022, 05:08:23pm","18-08-2022, 05:09:05pm"];

//
// sample output: [ "18-08-2022", "18-08-2022" ]
//
$dateMappedToYourFormat = array_map(function($dt) {
    return explode(",", $dt)[0]; // getting everything before comma
}, $arr);

echo implode(",", $dateMappedToYourFormat); //to view your result
```

Comment: bro but this is not printing it in array format.

Comment: What do you mean by "printing it in array format"?